# Contact with multiple entries in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a journey that sends an sms reminder to customers 48 hours before their appointment, using a data extension populated by an automation. The appointment information is stored on an custom salesforce object A and each contact can have multiple appointments, stored on separate A records. I also have an Object Activity record that should tick a checkbox on the custom object record once the SMS has fired for that record.

I am looking at the custom object record id as the primary key instead of the Contact id so that the SMS fires for multiple records for the same contact. Have also allowed the contact to re-enter the journey any time as well. However, the journey still only updates the last modified custom object record on Salesforce as part of the object activity . I have tried creating an attribute group  and using it in the decision split/ object activity but get the same issue. Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: What is your configuration with the object activity?

Comment: Hi @SwatiMishra, the activity updates the custom object based on the record id from the data extension. For multiple records, it is set to update the last modified record as there is no other option. Although, since the custom record id is the primary key, not sure why it would update only the last modified record instead of looking at each record separately (each custom object record appears as a separate row in the data extension and fires a separate sms).

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this problem yet? I'm facing the same one.